# Factor Ring $Z[i]/\langle3+i\rangle$ Ring operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have worked out that $Z[i]/\langle 3+i \rangle = \{[0],[1],[2],...,[9]\}$. Now I want to state the ring operations but I am confused between it being “addition/multiplication modulo 10 or modulo $\langle 3+i \rangle$.

Please would someone share some light on this.

I am thinking to write $[x]+[y]=[x+y \mod10]$

And similar for multiplication.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, you have $R/I$ the cosets modulo $I$, and not modulo $10$. Here $I=(3+i)$ is the principal ideal generated by $3+i$ in $R=\Bbb Z[i]$.

Comment: But if I write: $[x]+[y]=[x+y \mod(3+i)]$ it doesn’t look correct since x and y are both going to be integers?

Comment: If you already know that $0, 1, \dotsc, 9$ are coset representatives, note that $10\in\langle 3+i\rangle$ since $10 = (3+i)(3-i)$.

Comment: So 10 is the zero coset.  So should I write modulo 10 modulo <3+i> or not say any of them at all i.e is $[x]+[y]:=[x+y]$ fine by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map
$$
\varphi: \mathbb{Z} [x] \to \mathbb{Z}
$$

defined by $\varphi(1) = 1, \varphi(x) = -3$, let $I$ be the ideal generated by $x^2 + 1$, then $\varphi(I) \subseteq 10 \mathbb{Z}$, so this map descends to a map 
$$
\varphi: \mathbb{Z}[i] = \mathbb{Z} [x]/I \to \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Here $i$ denotes the class of $x$. This map is clearly surjective as $\varphi(1) = 1$, and it is injective. Indeed if $x = a  + bi$ is in the kernel then $a - 3b = 0 \mod 10$, then $x = b(3 + i) + 10k$ for some integer $k$, so $x \in I + 10\mathbb{Z}$ but $10\mathbb{Z} \subseteq I$ since $10 = (3 + i)(3-i)$. This gives your isomorphism, then the adition and multiplications are just the usual ones in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, e.g. $[3] + [8] = [11] = [1]$.

Does this answers your question?

Comment: I don’t really wish to show it is isomorphic to Z_10 and use that argument as I haven’t defined isomorphisms in my project yet